# Signal on Kernel parameter change

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I want to use parameter inside a kernel (3.x) module:

```
static unsigned short param = 0xff;
module_param(param, ushort, S_IRUGO | S_IWUGO);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(param, "a parameter");
```

Is there any possibility to detect changes on this parameter? Is there a signal which can use to call a service routine?

---

Here a full code example:

```
#include <linux/init.h>    
#include <linux/module.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");     
MODULE_AUTHOR("Alex"); 
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("test module."); 
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");             

static int param = 1;
module_param(param, int, S_IRUGO|S_IWUSR);

static int __init mod_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "param %d\n", param);
   return 0;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye!\n");
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

Now you can find the parameter under `/sys/module/<modulename>/parameters` and you can change the parameter like this (with root privileges):

```
echo 2 > /sys/module/ebb/parameters/param
```

I want to be notified about that change.

---

next step regarding to @Tsyvarev

```
#include <linux/init.h>    
#include <linux/module.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");     
MODULE_AUTHOR("Alex"); 
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("test module."); 
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");  

// int (*set)(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp);
// int (*get)(char *buffer, const struct kernel_param *kp);
int my_param_set_ushort(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    unsigned short* pvalue = kp->arg; // Pointer to actual parameter variable.
    int res = param_set_ushort(val, kp); // Use helper for write variable
    printk(KERN_INFO "setter talks\n");
    if( res==0 )
    {
        // Here you may execute additional actions when you write parameter.
        printk(KERN_INFO "set param %d\n", *pvalue);
    }
    return res;
}

const struct kernel_param_ops my_param_ops_ushort = 
{
    .set = &my_param_set_ushort, // Use our setter ...
    .get = &param_get_ushort, // .. and standard getter
};

unsigned short param = 0xff;
module_param_cb(param,    /*filename*/
    &my_param_ops_ushort, /*operations*/
    &param,               /* pointer to variable, contained parameter's value */
    S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR     /*permissions on file*/
);


static int __init mod_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "param %d\n", param);
   return 0;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye! (%d)\n",param);
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

as root I give this commands:

```
# insmod par.ko
# echo 146 > /sys/module/par/parameters/param
# rmmod par
```

and the kernel log */var/log/kernel.log* says:

```
Jan 23 14:27:37 alex-XMG kernel: [ 8332.492912] param 255
Jan 23 14:27:39 alex-XMG kernel: [ 8334.520044] setter talks
Jan 23 14:27:39 alex-XMG kernel: [ 8334.520052] set param 146
Jan 23 14:27:40 alex-XMG kernel: [ 8335.804338] Goodbye! (146)
```

Works like a charme!

Comment: Note: your variable `param` should be defined as `unsigned short param = 0xff;` since you've used `ushort` in `module_param()`

Comment: _uevent_ may be the thing you need. Linux uses uevent mechanism to notify the change of hardware. https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-reference/cha.udev.html#sec.udev.kernel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generic way for create kernel module parameter is using macro [module_param_cb](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L166):

```
/**
 * module_param_cb - general callback for a module/cmdline parameter
 * @name: a valid C identifier which is the parameter name.
 * @ops: the set & get operations for this parameter.
 * @perm: visibility in sysfs.
 *
 * The ops can have NULL set or get functions.
 */
#define module_param_cb(name, ops, arg, perm)
```

Parameter `ops` is a pointer to structure `struct kernel_param_ops`, which contains *operations* for given parameter. Functions called when parameter is written and read have followed definition in this structure:

```
int (*set)(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp);
int (*get)(char *buffer, const struct kernel_param *kp);
```

Here `char*` parameter is a NULL-terminated string, which is written to/read from the sysfs file, denoted given parameter. And `kp` is a pointer to parameter descriptor, where the most interested field is `.arg`: it is a 3rd argument to macro `module_param_cb` call. Using this field, setter and getter can be implemented *per-type* of the module parameter, that is having 5 `int` parameters for module doesn't require to write setters and getters for each of them.

Moreover, getters and setters for standard parameter types are already implemented, and they are actually used when you call `module_param` macro. So, if you want to *add* some functionality for the parameter's setter, you may reuse existed helpers:

```
int my_param_set_ushort(const char *val, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    unsigned short* pvalue = kp->arg; // Pointer to actual parameter variable.
    int res = param_set_ushort(val, kp); // Use helper for write variable
    if(!res)
    {
        // Here you may execute additional actions when you write parameter.
        printk(KERN_INFO "set param %d\n", *pvalue);
    }
    return res;
}

const struct kernel_param_ops my_param_ops_ushort = 
{
    .set = &my_param_set_ushort,  // Use our setter ...
    .get = &param_get_ushort,     // .. and standard getter
};

// Usage
unsigned short param = 0xff;
module_param_cb(param, /*filename*/
    &my_param_ops_ushort, /*operations*/
    &param, /* pointer to variable, contained parameter's value */
    S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR /*permissions on file*/
);
```

---

Having module parameter's writable by non-priveledged user normally is not good for security reasons. And kernel macros, which create module parameters, check that. That is why you have cryptic error in your module parameter's definition. Note, that in the example above `S_IWUSR` is used instead of `S_IWUGO`.

Comment: Do you now what the return value of `param_set_ushort` stands for? It declared in _moduleparam.h_ as `extern` but there are no information about the meaning of the return value.

Comment: `param_set_*` helpers are *ready-made* for `.set` callback, so they obey [rules for that callback](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L51): `Returns 0, or -errno.`. I have fixed my code.

Comment: Perfect! Now the last step. It is necessary to allow changes on parameters via `ioctl` to the _normal_ user. Is it a bad style to reuse the setter functions inside `ioctl`?

Comment: You can reuse any function if its *specification* is suitable for your purposes. But I unsure that reusing setter for `ioctl` is fit: the setter accepts pointer to null-terminated string in kernel space, while ioctl will, probably, accept a number. Or a pointer to buffer in user space. It looks to be better prepare *another* helper, which accepts a number, and use it in the setter (instead of `printk`) and inside ioctl.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Very cool!  I'll have to use this technique sometime.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your module parameter writable you can change that parameter via sysfs.  Once loaded, find your module under /sys, then find the module parameter and verify that it is writable (by root).  Try writing to it and see if it changes.

There are a few ways to detect changes to this variable.  You can use a kernel thread as one mechanism.

A better approach might be to use a sysfs or procfs entry.  Those have read/write handlers which are called upon reads and writes.

See here for an [`sysfs`-tutorial](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/)